# user account custom fields list of boolean type

Tags: entities, 9

In configuration form i need to create field with dinamic options. this needs to be rendered from user acount custom fields (i have create custom field earlier type of boolean) so i need reneder this field.

I have started from `$accountFields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('user', 'user');`

How do i filter out fields with boolean type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i have done this like this :

```
$definitions = array_filter(
        \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('user', 'user'),
        function ($fieldDefinition) {
          return $fieldDefinition instanceof \Drupal\field\FieldConfigInterface;
        }
      );
    $fields = array();
    foreach ($definitions as $field){

        if( $field->getType() === 'boolean') {
            
            $fields[$field->getName()] = $field->getLabel();
        }
    }
    return $fields;
```

I need it for selection list so the field returns and array field_name => field_label